# In solc 0.4.x assembly, how can I check if a non-constant function returns 'bool' or nothing?

Tags: solidity, assembly, returndata

I know how to do it for a constant function, for example:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25; 

contract Callee0 {function func() external pure returns (bool) {return false;}}
contract Callee1 {function func() external pure returns (bool) {return true;}}
contract Callee2 {function func() external pure {}}

contract Caller {
    bytes4 private constant FUNC_SELECTOR = bytes4(uint256(keccak256("func()") >> (256 - 4 * 8)));

    function funcReturns(address _callee) external view returns (bool) {
        uint256[1] memory output = [uint256(2)];
        bytes      memory input  = abi.encodeWithSelector(FUNC_SELECTOR);

        assembly {
            let success := staticcall(
                gas,            // gas remaining
                _callee,        // destination address
                add(input, 32), // input buffer (starts after the first 32 bytes in the `input` array)
                mload(input),   // input length (loaded from the first 32 bytes in the `input` array)
                output,         // output buffer
                32              // output length
            )
            if iszero(success) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }

        return output[0] < 2;
    }
}
```

Here is a Truffle 4.x test to assert this method:

```
contract("Caller", function(accounts) {
    it("test", async function() {
        const callee0 = await artifacts.require("Callee0").new();
        const callee1 = await artifacts.require("Callee1").new();
        const callee2 = await artifacts.require("Callee2").new();
        const caller  = await artifacts.require("Caller" ).new();
        const callee0_funcReturns = await caller.funcReturns(callee0.address);
        const callee1_funcReturns = await caller.funcReturns(callee1.address);
        const callee2_funcReturns = await caller.funcReturns(callee2.address);
        console.log();
        console.log(`callee0_funcReturns: ${callee0_funcReturns}`);
        console.log(`callee1_funcReturns: ${callee1_funcReturns}`);
        console.log(`callee2_funcReturns: ${callee2_funcReturns}`);
    });
});
```

The printout of this test is:

```
callee0_funcReturns: true
callee1_funcReturns: true
callee2_funcReturns: false
```

Would anybody know how to achieve the same when the function (`func` in the example above) is non-constant, **without** ending up having it changing the state of the contract?

Thank you!

Comment: One possibility is to delegatecall to yourself and then call your target. After determining the return value you can revert the delegatecall with a message indicating the result.

Comment: @Ismael: Thanks, but what exactly do you mean by *message*? Keep in mind that I need this as an on-chain solution (i.e., when calling from a contract, not from some web3 script, where there are a bunch of different ways to do this easily).

Comment: If you revert inside a delegatecall you cannot return any value, but you can return a string with a reason that you can hijack.